# Innefficient scss selectors being generated

Tags: css, sass

Im using Foundation by Zurb as a front-end framework. Below is the SCSS used to generate the basic layout of the homepage using the Semantic Grid Mixins Foundation supplies (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass-mixins.php).

The problem I am having is that it is creating massive selectors when I view them in the inspector in Chrome.

```
body.homepage div[role="main"] {

  header {
    @include outerRow();
    margin-bottom: 60px!important;
    h1 { @include column(12); }
  }


  & > section {
    margin-bottom: 120px!important;
  }


  .hero_container {
    @include outerRow();

    .video_holder {
      @include column(5);
      @include mobileColumn(4);
    }
    form {
      @include column(7);
      @include mobileColumn(4);

      legend {  }

      .personal_details {
        @include innerRow();

        label {
          @include column(6);
        }
      }

      .form_actions {
        @include innerRow();

        label { @include column(6); }
        .input_action { @include column(6); }

      }

    }
  }

  .reasons {
    @include outerRow();

    ul {
      list-style: none;

      li {
        @include column(4);
        @include mobileColumn(2);
        margin-bottom: $halfColumnGutter;

        p {
          padding: 12px;
          border: 1px solid #eee;
          background: #efefef;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .testimonials {
    @include outerRow();

    h4 { @include column(12); }

    ul {
      list-style: none;

      blockquote { @include column(3); @include mobileColumn(2); border-left: none; }
      p {
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        background: #efefef;
      }
    }

  }

  .register {
    @include outerRow();

    form {
      @include column(12);
      .personal_details {
        @include innerRow();
        margin-bottom: $halfColumnGutter;

        label {
          @include column(4);
        }
      }
      .extra_info {
        @include innerRow();
        margin-bottom: $halfColumnGutter;

        label {
          @include column(4);
        }
      }
      .form_actions {
        @include innerRow();

        label { @include column(4); }
        .input_action { @include offsetBy(4); @include column(2); }
      }
    }
  }
}
body.homepage.mobile div[role="main"] {

  .hero_container {

    form { margin-top: $halfColumnGutter; }
  }
}
```

Below is the output from the Chrome inspector when viewing the `label` in `.personal_details`

```
.top_bar .information_for_agencies, .top_bar .registration, header[role="banner"] .branding, header[role="banner"] .branding .logo, header[role="banner"] .branding .tagline, header[role="banner"] div[role="navigation"], footer[role="contentinfo"] section, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"], body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] header img.top_masthead, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_left, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_right, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.left_align, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.right_align, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.full_width, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] footer img.bottom_masthead, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"], body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] header img.top_masthead, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_left, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_right, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.left_align, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.right_align, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.full_width, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] footer img.bottom_masthead, body.two_columns div[role="main"] aside[role="complementary"], body.three_columns div[role="main"] section.adverts, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"], body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] header img.top_masthead, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_left, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_right, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.left_align, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.right_align, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.full_width, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] footer img.bottom_masthead, body.three_columns div[role="main"] aside[role="complementary"], body.homepage div[role="main"] header h1, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container .video_holder, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form .personal_details label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form .form_actions label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form .form_actions .input_action, body.homepage div[role="main"] .reasons ul li, body.homepage div[role="main"] .testimonials h4, body.homepage div[role="main"] .testimonials ul blockquote, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form .personal_details label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form .extra_info label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form .form_actions label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form .form_actions .input_action 
{
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding: 0 15px;
}
```

The guidelines for scss say not to go more than five levels deep, which I haven't. Is it something I am doing wrong? how can I write it more efficiently?

Comment: I suggest not selecting `div[role="main"]`, you simply could use a class like `.site-content` instead. Also using `body.homepage` is overqualified. `.homepage` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS that was created (i.e. the position, min-height, and padding) is not anything you have specified in your SCSS.  So it must be boilerplate generated by the mixins you're using, e.g. innerRow() and column().   I expect if you look at the Foundation source SCSS for those mixins you will see they'll be using @extend internally and hence generating the large selectors.  Either that or there's a bug in Foundation.